# KDE 4 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04, repository, kde4

I've been trying Plasma 5.7 and it was really slow to me. The startup time took me 15 seconds. So in short, I want to install KDE 4 in Ubuntu 16.04. Is it possible? I saw the Ubuntu Precise repository but I guess they are Plasma.